# Trying to use the nested styles of Less, but can't figure out how to get a comma after one class name and before the other

Tags: css, less

The output I want is this:

```
#brandA, .logo{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

What would my less code look like to achieve that output? I know about & selectors but that doesn't seem appropriate here.

**Update:**

I should have asked how would I write it if I wanted to nest the `.logo` inside the `#brandA` style I figured I can't put a comma after `#brandA` like so: `#brandA, { .logo{} }` because that would add the comma to all nested styles.

Comment: You can use exactly what you posted.  LESS doesn't prevent you from using the comma combinator.

Answer (score 2):

> If I wanted to nest the `.logo` inside the `#brandA` style I figured I can't put a comma after `#brandA` like so: `#brandA, { .logo{} }` because that would add the comma to all nested styles.

There are two things note here:

- Adding a `,` after `#brandA` will actually ***not add the comma to any of the nested blocks*** in the latest version of the Less compiler. The compiler would just ignore the comma.
- More importantly, you ***should not be nesting*** `.logo` into `#brandA`. Nesting isn't the correct way to achieve selector grouping (that is, comma separated selectors). You should either write it as-is in the question (or) use `:extend` option like in the below snippet.

```css
#brandA{ 
  padding: 10px;
  &.childA{
    color: red;
  }
  &.childB{
    color: steelblue;
  }
}
.logo{
  &:extend(#brandA);
}
```

---

If on the other hand the `.logo` element is a child (or a descendant element) of `#brandA` element then you could nest it as given in Erick Boileau's latest answer. For that scenario, nesting would be a valid choice.

Answer (score 1):

it's exactly the same with less , or with variable

```
#brandA, .logo{
  padding: @margin;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have asked how would I write it if I wanted to nest the .logo inside the #brandA style

I figured I can't put a comma after #brandA like so:

'#brandA, {
.logo{}
}'

because that would add the comma to all nested styles

Answer (score 0):

```
#brandA {
    text-align:center;
    > *{
        font-size:1.6rem;
    }
    .logo{
        padding: @margin;
    }
    .otherClass{
        a{
            color:red;
        }       
    }
}
```